# Installing macvtap on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: networking, qemu, virt-manager

I am trying to install a virtual machine by `virt-install` and it seems there is some problem by configuring `macvtap` interface:

```
virt-install --noautoconsole --name fgvm --memory 4096 --vcpus 4 --virt-type kvm --import --disk fortios.qcow2 --disk fgvm-logs.qcow2,size=1 --network type=direct,source=eth0,source_mode=bridge,model=virtio --osinfo detect=on,require=off
```

throws an error:

> WARNING  Using --osinfo generic, VM performance may suffer.
> Specify an accurate OS for optimal results.

> Starting install...
> Allocating 'fgvm-logs.qcow2'                                                                                                                                   > |    0 B  00:00:00 ...
> Removing disk 'fgvm-logs.qcow2'                                                                                                                                  > |    0 B  00:00:00
> ERROR    error creating macvtap interface macvtap0@eth0 (52:54:00:15:df:f9): Operation not supported
> Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
> If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
> virsh --connect qemu:///system start fgvm
> otherwise, please restart your installation.

Any idea or guide would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] with `ip l; uname -a` This problem may occur if the name is in use

Comment: @DanielT No, the name is not in use

Comment: @guiverc Ubuntu 23.10